# Flutter: how to prompt user for input using showDialog after tapping on ListTile, then using the input

Tags: flutter, dart

Assuming i have the codes below,

```
 Widget _myListView(BuildContext context) {
  return ListView(
    children: <Widget>[
      ListTile(
        title: Text('Sun'),
        onTap:() async{
           await showDialog<String>(
                    context:context,
                    --- not sure how to proceed from here --
                 }
        }
           Navigator.pop(context); //this code makes sure it go back to another page after done with the input processing.
      ),
      ListTile(
        title: Text('Moon'),
      ),
      ListTile(
        title: Text('Star'),
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

how to use the input onTap ListTile, run some method to use the input, and pop back to previous page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call function `_showMyDialog();` and see data in the console:

- I used `Row()` to work in landscape.

  ```
  final myController = TextEditingController();
  late String userData;

  Future<void> _showMyDialog() async {

    return showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false, // user must tap button!
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  controller: myController,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'Enter any data',
                    hintText: 'Enter any data',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: TextButton(
                  child: const Text('OK'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    userData = myController.text;
                    myController.text = '';
                    FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
                    print(userData);
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                  ),
              )
            ]
          )

        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    myController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
  ```